# Does "kinetic magic" (essentially telekinesis) imply unlimited energy?

Tags: magic, physics, thermodynamics

In [another question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/160428), I talked about a form of magic that converts metabolic energy (i.e. the energy produced by biological processes in "animals", which for this purpose includes e.g. yeast) into kinetic energy, with essentially unbounded¹ ability to precisely direct that kinetic energy.

In one answer / comment, Yakk [implied](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/160476/43697) that this would give someone wielding this ability nearly unlimited power:

> There is enough energy in a 1 kg rock to throw everything on the island of Manhattan 100 km into the sky.

On the one hand, I can see where someone might wonder if this could incarnate [Maxwell's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon). On the other hand, looking at the thought experiment literally, it would seem that opening and closing the door would itself require work, never mind all the problems that conductive heat transfer raises.

Is this — not the literal thought experiment, but the general idea — plausible? If so, what would be an example of an actual process by which one could extract "unlimited" energy using this "kinetic magic", and what limits could be applied to the wielding of magic that would prevent it, without preventing less, ah, "excessive" uses of magic? (The linked question notes some of the things I want to be able to do.)

I will assume:

- Initiation energy is limited to, *at best*, 2KWHr, and can be delivered at, *at best*, 5KW. Any process which would require exceeding those limits to start isn't feasible.
- Magic can't simply convert matter directly to energy.

The critical piece of the puzzle here is that magic can reduce entropy. For instance, it can turn a jumbled pile of blocks into a neat stack, or turn a bag of black and white marbles into piles separated by colors. Perhaps more importantly, it can² do these sorts of things on a molecular level, for example, fill a 1L container with pure argon taken from the surrounding atmosphere.

A related question could be, how do you measure the energy value of information of this nature? Knowing that, it may be that the "obvious" limitation is that this energy cost must also be paid.

Affirmative ("yes, this is world-breaking") answers should give a *detailed explanation* why this is the case, not just an assertion that it is.

(¹ Not really, but for the purpose of this question, we'll go with that.)

(² Actually, this is, at best, pushing the limits of what I'm going to allow, but again, for the sake of this question, we'll go with it.)

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense.  Metabolic energy release is pretty well understood (at least by biologists).  Nuclear energy release is well known but rather hard to achieve unless your "magic" changes atomic half-lives.  So what do you want to pretend your "magic" can do?  If it pulls energy from another universe or dimension,  then it's unlimited until  the last star dies (see Kilgore Trout)

Comment: If the only usable energy comes from metabolism then I'm unclear on how you are getting that much energy out of the rock.

Comment: To both commenters; your thoughts sounds suspiciously like an *answer*. @Yakk's comment suggests that some mechanism exists, but I don't understand how. This question is an attempt to ascertain if Yakk's comment is legitimate or bunk. I *also* don't understand how Yakk is proposing said energy conversion.

Comment: I don't think Yakk is saying you can use that energy via your magic. I think Yakk is just using nuclear energy to point out that entropy not energy is the constraining part of the problem.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think that's what I'm asking about. In particular, if I have "magic" that makes it possible to do things like pick out argon from the atmosphere to fill a container with *pure* argon, does "world-breaking super-power" follow as a corollary from the entropy implications of such an ability? If you can edit to make that more clear, go for it...

Comment: "Initiation energy is limited to, at best, 5KW, and at best 2KWHr". At least use the same unit. One is a power, the other is an energy

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, those are two *different* limitations. One is the maximum *rate* of energy (i.e. power), one is the maximum *total usage* of energy. "I can supply your rocket with up to 50 gallons of H₂ at up to 10 gallons per second. If it needs to consume fuel faster than that to get overcome gravity, or needs to consume more total fuel to reach its target height, then you are SOL." Two different values for the same limit wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem; you read the first "energy" in the literal, scientific sense, whereas I was using it in a more colloquial sense. Reworded.

Comment: Generally, you have two options - either your magic is working in concert with existing physics (and you can convert traditional energy to mana and vice versa), or it is not, and essentially "anything goes". If it the latter case, your can put restrains on exactly how far it goes.

Comment: @Alexander, as much as possible, the former; immediate energy conversion, and also with no intermediate "mana". (I'll allow *some* buffering, but only for maybe a few seconds.)

Comment: @Matthew Ok, if you want to stick with energy conservation law, then there will be no "Maxwell daemons". Thought process, actually, becomes straightforward. You need to 1) select energy source for your magic (what object will it drawn from and in which form - chemical, nuclear etc); 2) Fixate "before" and "after" state of your source object. The difference in energy levels will be your energy balance to play with; 3) Calculate how much this derived energy can give you, in terms of telekinesis or other application.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are talking magic, you can impose limits however you wish.  I'll tell you what I would do though.

First limitation is to consider Magic to be energy.  Seems like you are doing this already.  It gives you a limit based in understood physics.  You can neither create or destroy energy just like you can neither create or destroy Matter.  You can rearrange things down to a molecular level, but you still do business with the laws of physics.  Conservation of Mass and Conservation of Energy are key concepts here.

Your Second limitation would be limited to the energy your Magic user can glean from *metabolic processes*.  This takes away the ability to use the 1kg rock to toss Manhattan around.  A metabolic process is loosely defined by layman like myself is the process of taking something you take in, break it down to useful compounds, then combine it to release energy.  In an animal, this is breaking down food, converting it to glucose, and combining it with oxygen to release energy (laymans description)

The upshot is that your magic user cannot use any more energy than they can take in and process as food.  What they move, whether it's with their body or mind, takes the same amount of calories.  If it takes 20 Calories to pick up boxes on your left and move it to your right using your hands, then it will take the same amount of calories to do it with your brain.  If you want to travel a certain distance with brain power, it will burn the same amount of calories as you walking or running the same distance.  This puts a solid limit to magic and keeps magic users from getting ridiculously OP.

You did bring up Magic being able to combat entropy.  Humans do this with their hands all the time.  To stack a pile of bricks will simply cost the same amount of calories as walking over and using your hands.  Separating colored marbles is the same.  The thing about Entropy is that it takes over when you stop paying attention.

Now comes some of the cool stuff.  Humans are prevented from ultra fine manipulation of stuff like molecules *without tools* because fingers prevent that kind of control.  Magic is different.  It is the Magic, which has no form, that does the work and can therefore grab that argon molecule, and only the argon molecule, and transfer it to the glass.  The ability to manipulate the physical shifts from the skill of the hand to the skill of the brain.  You are still limited by how much energy you can derive from food.  You're Magic User still won't be able to lift a 20 ton block without tools and help.  However, your Magic User will be able to pull the rope attached to a pulley system that can lift the 20 ton block.  In addition, imagination becomes your limiting factor.  Your Magic User could do whatever they imagine, like maybe assassinating an enemy by pinching the carotid artery from 30 feet away.  Or spooking a general's horse from a distance.  Dice manipulation, moving the barrel of a gun before it's fired, and so on.

That's how I would put limits on magic use.  It's all about counting calories

Comment: I'm not sure this actually answers the question. You've basically stated that, at a macroscopic scale, anyway, I *can* create Maxwell's Demon. Take separating marbles. The argument why this doesn't decrease entropy is because the increased "information energy" is offset by the calories my brain burned in to "produce" that information. But... how do I measure that cost when I instead separate grains of sand, or molecules of atmosphere? At some point, that cost must become "very high", or I *think* (and @Yakk claims) it leads to world-breaking powers.

Comment: That said, thanks for the answer anyway! You're pretty much bang-on with how I envision this to work. (Hehe... hadn't thought about dice; needless to say, use of magic in a casino is very, *very* banned. It's off topic here, but yes, there are ways to tell when magic is used; otherwise, as you also noted, it's *way* to easy to do things like kill people without leaving a trace.)

Comment: @Matthew One way to prevent the world breaking aspect would be to keep the calorie cost to be the same as moving the molecule with your hand. You still have the cost of moving the arm in addition to the amount of energy required by the payload, no matter how small.  If you want to fill a glass with argon then you would have to make that motion once for each molecule and that carries a caloric cost that would be incredibly high because the motion would be repeated billions of times.  Call it the invisible hand.

Comment: Yeah... that could work, but seems rather contrived. (Also, it would probably break a lot of the things I *want* to be able to do, like remove dirt from clothes.) I'd prefer to be able to quantify the associated entropy costs.

Comment: @Matthew  The Maxwell's Demon effect could be mitigated by the speed of human reaction.  Even if you could perceive the motion of molecules, could you react fast enough to trigger the gate? And even if you could, what would be caloric cost to trigger a neuron to fire to trigger the gate.  If you figure one neuron fire to activate the gate, trying to run a Maxwell gate would light your head up like a Christmas Tree.

Comment: @Matthew You might also run into a value add problem.  You mention removing dirt from clothes. Lets shift the metaphor a touch to digging a trench.  You could do it with a regular shovel, or you could do it with a small garden trowel.  Both methods will work, but one takes infinitely more energy.  Back to clothes, You could remove dirt by the particle, or you could remove several bits or clumps at once and then go back for fine finish work.  Or you could just put the garment through a washing machine and then magically go back for the stains.

Comment: Mental capacity seems a good intuitive proxy for information entropy — to do something with magic, you have to fully understand/conceptualise it.  So getting dirt off clothing is fine — it’s no more complicated than scraping mud off a wagon, just at a smaller scale.  But “Maxwell’s demon” situations are too complex: un-stirring a cup of coffee would be like sorting a room full of red and blue marbles into two colours, while a hurricane blows through; visualising it all at once is mentally impossible, but doing it one marble at a time is just too slow to beat the hurricane.